# dynamic query with laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

hello friends need a hand with this query, failed to make it work, I'm new with laravel, I have 3 models:

**DiscussCategory**

```
class DiscussCategory extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'discuss_category';
protected $guarded = array('id');

public function status() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Status');
}

public function discuss() {
    return $this->hasMany('Discuss');
}
```

}

**Discuss**

```
class Discuss extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'discuss';
protected $guarded = array('id');

public function discussReplies() {
    return $this->hasMany('DiscussReplies');
}

public function discussCategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo('DiscussCategory');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Users');
}
```

}

**Users**

```
class Users extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'users';

protected $guarded = array('id');
protected $hidden = array('password');

public function getAuthIdentifier() {
    return $this->getKey();
}

public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}

public function getReminderEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}

public function discussReplies() {
    return $this->hasOne('DiscussReplies');
}

public function discuss() {
    return $this->hasMany('Discuss');
}
```

}

and this how I try to show the query in view

```
                    @foreach($data as $category)
                {{$category->discuss->last()->users->nickname}}
                @endforeach
```

if you run a foreach manages to get users, but I just want the name of the last user to post a discuss

```
Trying to get property of non-object 

appreciate a hand, insurance is not much, but I have little experience
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Discuss` model change following method:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Users');
}
```

To this (use `user` not `users`)

```
public function user() {
    // Assumed one discuss belongs to one user
    return $this->belongsTo('Users'); // Rename Users to User and use User here
}
```

Also you should use singular name for all of your models for example, use `User` instead of `Users`.